# Hanging program after trying to free allocated memory

Tags: c, malloc

I'm not quite sure what is wrong with my current program and I have reach a bit of a road block:

```
(*ptr).Name = (char*)malloc(strlen(record+1));
strcpy((*ptr).Name, record); 
free((*ptr).Name); //problem area
```

*ptr is a pointer that points to a structure that has various fields. After I copy some data into the Name field I want to free my allocated memory. When I step through my program I get no errors rather just a hanging program that will not continue after I try and free the memory. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: We can't debug incomplete code. Your problem likely stems from code not shown. Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: `(*ptr).Name` is more commonly written as `ptr->Name`

Comment: oh wow i didn't see the record+1 being incorrect thank you.

Comment: `strlen(record+1)` has the *opposite* effect to that intended ;) that is, one shorter.

Comment: Thank you, everything works as intended!

Comment: [don't cast malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 2):

```
(*ptr).Name = (char*)malloc(strlen(record+1)); //This is the problem!
strcpy((*ptr).Name, record); 
free((*ptr).Name); //problem area              //Better practice to use free(ptr->Name
```

Fix:

```
ptr->Name = (char*)malloc(strlen(record)+1);   //(record+1) in previouse code was doing 
                                                 //the opposite of what it was intended to do
strcpy(ptr->Name, record); 
free(ptr->Name);
```

Comment: `ptr->.Name` should be `ptr->Name`